# Mongodb aggregate group by then conditional sum, or, filter, push, using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Can someone please help to convert this query to C# .NET core?

```
db.getCollection("accout").aggregate().match({ $or: [{"clientnum1": "xxxx"},{ "clientnum2": ""}], "accNo":"00001","currCd":"INR"} ).sort({mktValueBased:-1}).group({_id: "$catName",holdings:{$push: {name: "$secName",currCd: "$currCd",currCdBased: {$cond: [{$in: ["$serviceType", ["a","b","c"]]}, "$Cd", "$Cd"]},cost : "$cost",costBased : {$cond: [{$in: ["$serviceType", ["a","b","c"]]}, "$AccBased", "$costBased"]},mktVal: "$mktValue",mktValBased: {$cond: [{$in: ["$serviceType", ["a","b","c"]]}, "$mktAccBased", "$mktValueBased"]},uPL: round({ $subtract: ["$mktValue","$cost"] }, 2),uPLPct: round({$cond: [{$eq: ["$cost",0]}, 0, { $multiply: [{ $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$mktValue","$cost"] }, {$cond: [{$gt: ["$cost",0] },"$cost",1]} ]}, 100] }]},2)}}}).sort( { _id: 1, data: 1 } ).group({ _id: null, data: {$push: {groupName: "$_id",holdings: "$holdings"}}}).project( { _id: 0, data: 1 }})
```

`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $or: [ { "clientnum1": "xxxx" }, { "clientnum2": "" } ],
      "accNo": "00001",
      "currCd": "INR"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { mktValueBased: -1 }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$catName",
      holdings: {
        $push: {
          name: "$secName",
          currCd: "$currCd",
          currCdBased: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: [ "$serviceType", [ "a", "b", "c" ] ] },
              "$Cd",
              "$Cd"
            ]
          },
          cost: "$cost",
          costBased: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: [ "$serviceType", [ "a", "b", "c" ] ] },
              "$AccBased",
              "$costBased"
            ]
          },
          mktVal: "$mktValue",
          mktValBased: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: [ "$serviceType", [ "a", "b", "c" ] ] },
              "$mktAccBased",
              "$mktValueBased"
            ]
          },
          uPL: { $round: [ { $subtract: [ "$mktValue", "$cost" ] }, 2 ] },
          uPLPct: {
            $round: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: [ "$cost", 0 ] },
                  0,
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      {
                        $divide: [
                          { $subtract: [ "$mktValue", "$cost" ] },
                          { $cond: [ { $gt: [ "$cost", 0 ] }, "$cost", 1 ] }
                        ]
                      },
                      100
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { _id: 1, data: 1 }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: { groupName: "$_id", holdings: "$holdings" } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { _id: 0, data: 1 }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to  StackOverflow! It would be nice if you'll show us what you have tried first. People here don't do code-conversion-services. Kindly read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Studio 3T plugin to convert it into c# code.

Note: Studio 3T is a licensed product but you can use there 30-day free trial

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.